# Laplace transform of homogenous differential equation with no initial values

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I have the following differential equation:

$$
  \frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+5\frac{dy}{dt}+6y=0 \\
     y(0)=0\\
     \frac{dy}{dt}(0) = 0\\
$$

To solve this differential equation I want to use the Laplace Transform.
However, when solving this equation I get the following:

$$
  s^2Y(s)+5sY(s)+6Y(s)=0\\
  Y(s)(s^2+5s+6)=0\\
  Y(s)=0
$$
Thus, according to Laplace there is no solution. However, using the standard way of solving second-order differential equations, there is a solution. Namely:

$$
y(t)=C_1e^{-3t}+C_2e^{-2t}
$$

A hint of this solution can be found if we refactor the laplace expression:
$$
s^2+5s+6\\
(s+3)(s+2)
$$

Can you spot the mistake or misinterpretation in this derivation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a difference between "the solution is zero" and "there is no solution".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the solution does exist, its the constant function zero. If you use the fact that $y(0)=y'(0) =0$ to
$$
y(t)=C_1e^{-3t}+C_2e^{-2t}
$$
You'll get that $C_1=C_2=0$, so $y(t) =0$ and there is not any contradiction

Comment: ah yes, I have spotted my mistake now. Thanks for pointing it out!